# Could you explain what this phrase means in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Sentence is that. "He drank slowly, like a connoisseur, lingering on the taste and still looking about him at the cliffs and up at our signboard."

I read this sentence couple of times. But I didn't get what "**lingering on the taste**" means.

Comment: I means he did not swallow each mouthful right away, but let it roll around his mouth first, to savour its flavour. Similarly if you are passing a shop with nice music playing, you might linger to enjoy the music.

Comment: Besides ***the drinker lingering on the taste***, we can also speak of ***the taste lingering*** (with or without an explicit preposition-based adverbial clause, such as ***...on the tongue, ...in his mouth***). Which makes ***linger*** significantly different to ***savour*** (the drinker can savour the taste, but we can't speak of the taste savouring anything, even though it can certainly *linger*).

Comment: Note that ***most "lingerings" are bad*** (or at the very least, "bittersweet, poignant"). The cited example is a relatively uncommon context where the lingering concerns a *pleasant* experience, but you should be careful about extending the verb to other contexts where the "negative, unpleasant" associations might have an unwanted effect.

Comment: I have had a very large number of pleasant lingerings in my life, so many that I have to disagree that most are bad.

Comment: It's a less common version of the more common *the taste lingering on his tongue*. Generally, taste lingers (somewhere). And while *he's lingering on*, with nothing else, is fine, *(someone) lingering on (something)* is uncommon and, at least to me, sounds strange.

Comment: Peter said that Mr Jones, who liked musical theatre, lived with a _friend_, lingering on the last word suggestively.

Answer (score 1):

Linger means "spend a long time (a longer time than needed) in a place or doing something".

He is drinking something, perhaps wine, and is lingering by drinking it more slowly then one would normally, to completely enjoy the taste of the wine.